# Pushing in child repository also effect parent repository why?

Tags: git

I forked a repository `ChildRepo` from `ParentRepo`,Then i clone `ChildRepo` and

```
ChildRepo/project_name > git checkout develop 
ChildRepo/project_name (develop) > git status //modified: README.md
ChildRepo/project_name (develop) > git remote -v //git@github.abc.com:cm/project_name.git
ChildRepo/project_name (develop) > git add .
ChildRepo/project_name (develop) > git commit -m "Style"
ChildRepo/project_name (develop) > git push
```

After pushing in `ChildRepo` , these changes are reflect in both `ParentRepo` and `ChildRepo` , i dont no why ,please let me know, As i want these commit only in `ChildRepo`

Answer (score 1):

You should check the remote-url you got from `git remote -v`, it should point to your own forked repository (child repository), not the parent repository. If it is pointing to parent repository, then add a new remote url pointing to child repository using,

```
git remote add upstream <child repo's remote-url>
```

Then you can push your changes to only child repository using

```
git push <upstream/origin (whichever is pointing to child repo)> <Your branch name>
```

Comment: It's upstream and origin both are pointing to childrepo .then also it is showing..I dont know why